# Does JWT Grant in Dousign require additional configutation when in Production

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect

I have tried [Node.js Quickstart Demos](https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-node) and was able to grant consent using JWT Grant in development. Recently I have applied for Go-Live and now my app integration is live in Docusign. I have also configured the live app settings. How can I test JWT-Grant with Quickstart examples using production configuration? It keeps throwing this error at me and there is only little support out there regarding the After Go-Live process.

```
Error: Target account true not found!
    at _DsJwtAuth._getUserInfo [as getUserInfo] (D:\HyperloopCMT-Docusign-node.js\lib\DSJwtAuth.js:138:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async log (D:\HyperloopCMT-Docusign-node.js\lib\DSJwtAuth.js:181:22)
(node:22912) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Target account true not found!
    at _DsJwtAuth._getUserInfo [as getUserInfo] (D:\HyperloopCMT-Docusign-node.js\lib\DSJwtAuth.js:138:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async log (D:\HyperloopCMT-Docusign-node.js\lib\DSJwtAuth.js:181:22)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

Here is how appSettings.json looks :

```
{
  "dsClientId": "CID",
  "dsClientSecret": "PROD_INT_SECRET",
  "dsJWTClientId": "CID",
  "privateKeyLocation":  "config/private.key",
  "impersonatedUserGuid": "APP_USERNAME_FROM_PRODUCTION",
  "signerEmail": "abc@ex.com",
  "signerName": "XXXX",
  "appUrl": "http://localhost:5000",
  "production": true,
  "debug": true,
  "sessionSecret": "12345",
  "allowSilentAuthentication": true,
  "targetAccountId": true,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've populated `targetAccountId` with the value `true`, where I suspect you want to include your actual DocuSign account ID.